# SCRIPT1014: Invalid character `

Tags: javascript, html, string, internet-explorer-8, microsoft-edge

My code:

```
htmlString+= `<img id=\"image_${result.id}\" src=\"${result.image}\" width=\"100%\">`;
                $('#addItem').before(htmlString);
```

I use `` because I need ${variable.attribute} in code, my code is complex, operation + in string is difficult.

Comment: use  $( result).attr( "checked" )

Comment: IE8 doesn't support Template strings. Use `'<img id="image_' + result.id + '" src="' + result.image + '" width="100%">'`

Comment: Thank for support but I test in edge browser and I catch error.

Comment: Use a transpiler. Babel is the most common right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
htmlString+= '<img id="image_${result.id}" src="${result.image}" width="100%">';
$('#addItem').before(htmlString);
```